# Integrating a Delta Function Over a Hypersphere

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, change-of-variable

This question came up while trying to calculate the density of states for an ideal gas in statistical mechanics. After some physics, I've found that I need to evaluate the following integral:

$$I=\int \delta\left (\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{|\vec{p_{i}}|^{2}}{2m}-E\right ) d^{3}p_{1}...d^{3}p_{N}$$
Where $m$ and $E$ are constants, and the integral is taken over $3N$ dimensional space.

I realise that $\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{|\vec{p_{i}}|^{2}}{2m}=E$, describes a $3N$ dimensional hypersphere, so $I$ would be an integration over its surface area.
At this point I'm havinga  it of touble visualizing the geometry of the integral.

My notes now define $P=\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_{i}^{2}$, and write $d^{3}p_i...d^{3}_N=dPP^{3N-1}d\Omega_{3N}$, where $\Omega_{3N}$, is the unit solid angle in $3N$ dimensions. From here, as the argument of the delta function has no angular dependence, the integral can be split up, to give:

$$I=\int d\Omega_{3N}\int \frac{P^{3N-1}\delta(P-\sqrt{2mE})}{P/m} dP$$

The first integral is clearly the surface area of the $3N$ dimensional hypersphere, which I've been able to calculate. The second integral is trivial, by setting $P=\sqrt{2mE}$, and evaluating the integrand.

Where I'm having trouble is in the change of variables to $P$ and $\Omega$. In my notes it is done quite arbitrarily. I think I understand it physically ($P$ is the length of the $3N$ dimensional momentum vector, which sweeps over the hypersphere), but mathematically I can't justify it. I've always had trouble with change of variables in this kind of situationa and any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: The change of variables from $d^3p_1...d^3p_N$ to $P^{3N-1}dP\;d\Omega_{3N}$ is just a change from rectangular coordinates to [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_element) in $3N$ dimensions. We do this for the same reason that we use polar coordinates to evaluate $\int_{\Bbb R^2}\exp(-(x^2+y^2))\;dx\;dy$: the integral is easier to evaluate this way. 

Also, to be more precise, your integral over $d\Omega_{3N}$ is the surface area of the boundary of the _unit_ $3N-$ball.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Fourier integral representation of the delta function,

$$\delta\left (\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{|\vec{p_{i}}|^{2}}{2m}-E\right ) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega \ e^{i \omega \left (\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{|\vec{p_{i}}|^{2}}{2m}-E\right )}$$

and change the order of the integrations, you will be left with Gaussian integrals over the $\vec{p}_i$-s and the final integral over $\omega$ can be solved using the $\Gamma$ function (it will just give you the surface area of the unit $3N-1$ sphere).